# Integral from function approximations

Tags: interpolation, integration, approximation

I have some data which I cannot manage to model and fit with a known function, so let’s say that they are a sample from the unknow function $f(x)$, which look a sort of skewed bell-shaped distribution.

Given $a,b \in  \mathbb{R}$ and $\vec{w}$ some parameters of the unknown function:

$$\int_{a}^{b} f(x,\vec{w}=\vec{w_1}) = A \,,$$

I would like to know if there is an approximate method that allow me to sampling or to have a function approximator of $f(x,\vec{w}=\vec{w_2})$ s.t. $$\int_{a}^{b} f(x,\vec{w}=\vec{w_2}) = A^c$$ where $c \in     \mathbb{R}$.
What I'm interested in are the tails of distribution $f(x,\vec{w}=\vec{w_2})$.

Comment: Can you give us more information about "I cannot manage to model and fit with a known function"?

Comment: Are you just looking for any kind of function $g(x)$ that satisfies the second equation? How about $g(x)=\frac{A^c}{b-a}$?

Comment: Sorry I explained really badly, I reformulated the question.

Comment: I still don't understand. The function $f(x,w_2)$ is what it is. You can't *choose* what integral it has, the integral *just is*.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth one could simply write $\int_{a}^{b} f(x,\vec{w}) = A^c$ in this case choosing the proper values of the parameters $\vec{w}$ I think one can surely "choose" the integral $A^c$

Comment: @StefanoBarone I just don't think I understand what you're asking. You can't "choose" the value of the integral $\int_0^1 (-xw^2) \, dx$. It is $-w^2/2$, whether you like that or not, and if $A^c=1$, you're just out of luck.